# can not read serial port using php or nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, arduino, port

I have tried to read serial port data sending with arduino by php or nodejs and I couldn't. I think my codes are correct. I think the problem is permission access reading serial port limited by windows or browser but i'm not sure. although the software of arduino can read data.
when I run my codes, arduio sends data over and over but nothing to show data.
can you help me?!

Here my php codes:

```
    <?php

//-- settings --//

//brainboxes serial ports
$portName = "COM5";
$baudRate = 9600;
$bits = 8;
$spotBit = 1;

header( 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8' ); 
?>
Serial Port Test
================
<?php


function echoFlush($string)
{
    echo $string . "\n";
    flush();
    ob_flush();
}

if(!extension_loaded('dio'))
{
    echoFlush( "PHP Direct IO does not appear to be installed for more info see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dio.php" );
    exit;
}

try 
{
    //the serial port resource
    $bbSerialPort;
    
    echoFlush(  "Connecting to serial port: {$portName}" );
    
    if (strtoupper(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3)) === 'WIN') 
    { 
        $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR );
        //we're on windows configure com port from command line
        exec("mode {$portName} baud={$baudRate} data={$bits} stop={$spotBit} parity=n xon=on");
    } 
    else //'nix
    {
        $bbSerialPort = dio_open($portName, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK );
        dio_fcntl($bbSerialPort, F_SETFL, O_SYNC);
        //we're on 'nix configure com from php direct io function
        dio_tcsetattr($bbSerialPort, array(
            'baud' => $baudRate,
            'bits' => $bits,
            'stop'  => $spotBit,
            'parity' => 0
        ));
    }
    
    if(!$bbSerialPort)
    {
        echoFlush( "Could not open Serial port {$portName} ");
        exit;
    }
    
    // send data
    
    $dataToSend = "HELLO WORLD!";
    echoFlush( "Writing to serial port data: \"{$dataToSend}\"" );
    $bytesSent = dio_write($bbSerialPort, $dataToSend );
    echoFlush( "Sent: {$bytesSent} bytes" );
    
    //date_default_timezone_set ("Europe/London");
    
    $runForSeconds = new DateInterval("PT10S"); //10 seconds
    $endTime = (new DateTime())->add($runForSeconds);
    
    echoFlush(  "Waiting for {$runForSeconds->format('%S')} seconds to recieve data on serial port" );
    
    while (new DateTime() < $endTime) {
    
        $data = dio_read($bbSerialPort, 256); //this is a blocking call
        if ($data) {
            echoFlush(  "Data Recieved: ". $data );
        }
    }
    
    echoFlush(  "Closing Port" );
    
    dio_close($bbSerialPort);

} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echoFlush(  $e->getMessage() );
    exit(1);
} 

?>
```

Error in php:
"**Warning**:  dio_open(): cannot open file COM5 with flags 2 and permissions 0: Permission denied in **C:\xampp\htdocs\serialreading\SerialPortTest.php** on line **42**
Could not open Serial port COM5"

Here my nodejs codes:

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    port = 8888;

//Server start
server.listen(port, () => console.log('on port' + port))

//user server
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.on('connection', onConnection);

var connectedSocket = null;
function onConnection(socket){
    connectedSocket = socket;
}

//Arduino to CMD
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const usbport = new SerialPort('COM5');
const parser = usbport.pipe(new Readline());
parser.on('data', function (data) {
    io.emit('data', { data: data });
});
```

Error in nodejs:
"Could Not get"

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: Add that info to the question please, not comments. Thanks.